# Want a new line(\n) element in Assert.AreEqual()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I haven't entered any username and password and click on login, I'll get message:

> The username field is required.
>
> The password field is required.

They are in unorderedlist in HTML.

In the code I'm using

```
Assert.AreEqual("The Username field is required.\nThe Password field is required.",
        loginPage.ValidationMsgText,
        "Error at Validaion message with no credentials");
```

but it is always failing the test case.

I also tried

```
Assert.IsTrue(loginPage.ValidationMsgText
        .Contains("The Username field is required.The Password field is required."));
```

but it didn't work. I'm new to automation and need some help.

My HTML:

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <ul>
        <li>The Username field is required.</li>
       <li>The Password field is required.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why you are passing 3 arguments in `Assert.AreEqual` , it should have 2 arguments , Expected and Actual.

Comment: @HelpingHands The third one is the error message thrown in case of failure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243446.aspx

Comment: @Slanec - I see, I was checking with java.

Comment: @HelpingHands Java also has this optional message as it's quite useful. See e.g. [`Assert.assertEquals()`](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)).

Comment: What's the print out of the `loginPage.ValidationMsgText`?

Comment: Turcia, I'm getting these 2 statements in 2 different lines "The Username field is required.      The Password field is required." I couldn't format it properly in the comments. But they are in 2 lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
Assert.IsTrue(
loginPage.ValidationMsgText.Contains("The Username field is required.") &&
loginPage.ValidationMsgText.Contains("The Password field is required.")
);
```

Also, while debugging, you can verify actual value of ValidationMsgText and use the corresponding char. (Maybe instead of /n it would be better to use Environment.NewLine)

Comment: I was struggling for this for so long. Your solution worked for me. Thanks. Is there a way to use Assert.AreEqual() in this scenario. @Pitroslav

Comment: I'm curious how you're getting and (maybe) concatenating your text from the `li` tags. As Piotroslav mentioned in his answer, you need to check the actual value from `loginPage.ValidationMsgText` and act based on that.

Comment: Cosmin, this is the only scenario where I'm getting 2 different strings. The output will be "The username field required. The password field required". It comes in 2 different lines. using Assert.AreEqual(), the 2 statements will be in the same line. I'm getting an error might be because of spacing, which I couldn't find out. So I tried using Assert.IsTrue(). I really appreciate if you could tell me with assert.AreEqual().

Comment: It is quite easy. Once you know exact content of loginPage.ValidationMsgText you can store it as a string and use it in Assert.AreEqual(loginPage.ValidationMsgText, myString);  But you still need to know how those two <li> parts are merged into ValidationMsgText

Comment: public string ValidationMsgText
        {
            get
            {
                IWebElement validationMsgs = Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".validation-summary-errors>ul"));
                return validationMsgs.Text;
            }
        }. This is how it's coded. When I print the output, it's displaying text in 2 lines. The Username field required.  The password is required in 2 lines. Sorry I couldn't format the comments. This is the first time asking a question in stack overflow. Please don't min.

Comment: This is not what Cosmin and me were talking about. 
Set a debug point onto return validationMsgs.Text; and then look exactly what is inside. Or you can remove from it both strings you verify and see what is left. Then you will see what to add into your previous assertion.